# ASP:NET - IIS Issue with 3rd Party DLL

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, dll

I'm using 3rd party dll files in an asp.net application. Everything works fine in dev environment.

At deploy moment, I had imported the app package to IIS Default Site for testing. Everything worked like a charm.

The problems began when I needed to create a new website at IIS (other than Default Site). So I had created a new site, a new dir path(not wwwroot), got some permissions issues, witch I solved. Then I started the app and seems to work well, but I when tried to access a specific page that use a reference for a 3rd party dll, the application raise an exception (bad name or number...) from a function owned by 3rd party dll.

It's quite strange that everything works great in IIS Default Site and blow up when I use a new IIS Site. Don't know what to do, any ideas? Thanks

Comment: *Bad name or number* looks like an old VB6 error message. Can you post the exact exception you receive?

Comment: I agree with @FrédéricHamidi; the DLL is probably some old VB6 COM library (or C++ ATL) which needs to be registered with the system. Sometimes, a simple `regsrv32.exe /i <your_dll_library>.dll` command will do the trick to register it with Windows. In other cases, you may need to actually run some installer that was provided with the library.

Comment: The libraries are referenced in vs project and compiled in one single dll. This exception does not happen when I deploy the app in Default Site App Pool. 

"System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A0034): Bad file name or number\r\n at Interop...."

Answer (score 0):

Check your application pool you are pointing to in the new site and make sure it is set to the correct version of .NET. When you created the new site you might have just taken the default app pool.

Comment: This is also a good thing to check. Also, be sure that you also check the "bitness" of the app pool and that it matches with the "bitness" of the library you're trying to use.

Comment: I'm stuck with this for several days, I already tried to replicate every single configuration in new App Pool to match Default App Pool configurations! The app it's configured to run in 32bits mode and also I change .NET from 2.0 to 4.0 (required).

Answer (score -1):

"Solved", changing the new Application Pool to Default Application Pool. Still don't know why the exception occurs with new pools.